# Blender Texture Painting problem: Draw won't work but fill will? Video included

Tags: modeling

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSn9gDS2ljs

Hi there

I'm a complete beginner on Blender Guru's doughnut tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nht2RoYBUfA
After 5:39 I can't continue because draw won't work. Fill will work so I can make the texture a solid colour, and I know it's all linked up properly because of this.

When I try to draw, nothing happens except my mac slows right down for a second with a loading wheel, then nothing changes.

Trawled a lot of forums and videos but nothing really works

Comment: hello, please pack your images (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) then share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1):

You have created a texture in your *Brush Settings* (and it's completely black), just close it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't upload the blender file because it is too big, but if you gave me an email to send it to I would send it over for you to take a look at.

I would really appreciate your help :)

Lewis

Comment: please don't use the Your Answer field to post comment, instead click on "Add a comment"

Comment: Sorry, when I tried it said I needed 30 credits! Really appreciate this, thank you so much